# Is the cosmic event horizon viewed from Andromeda different from the one viewed from Earth?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, space-expansion, event-horizon, estimation

If the most distant galaxies we see in deep space are in proximity of our cosmic event horizon does it mean that if we were on Andromeda galaxy and looking in the same direction we would see objects that are beyond the Earth cosmic event horizon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the observable universe as bordered by the cosmic microwave background (which is not a true event horizon, just an opaque surface), then yes, the portion of the universe observable from Andromeda is slightly shifted relative to ours. They'd see different patterns in the cosmic microwave background. They might just barely be able to see a few extra galaxies.

If you're talking about the theoretical particle horizon (what we'd see if the CMBR and everything beyond it was transparent), then we don't know. It depends on what happened in the early universe.

If you're talking about the future cosmological horizon (the infinite-time limit of the particle horizon), that depends on the limit of your position as the time goes to infinity, not your position at any finite time. If someone from Andromeda and someone from the Milky Way stayed within a few billion light years of each other until the end of time, then they'd have the same future cosmological horizon.